# Is there any option to create few ArrayLists automaticly with loop?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have project to create storage, and i am using ArrayLists for every room.
Is there any solution to create more than one ArrayList in loop ?
I just want to reduce amount of code.
Quotes/brackets and other stuff arent working. Is there any solution for beginner?

I was trying something like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++}{
ArrayLists list[i] = new ArrayLists();
}
```

---

```
    ArrayList list0 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
    //up to 10
```

Comment: myArrayList.add(new ArrayList()); but for a limited number, an array would be better

Comment: Then ArrayList in ArrayList right ? i mean ur first part of answer.

Comment: The problem with your example is that the array list is created in the scope of the loop, when it leaves an iteration of the loop the array list destructor will be called.

Comment: @SPlatten oh yeah, you are right. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

use [arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) and get rid off the loop

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] al = new ArrayList[5]; 
Arrays.fill(al, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Comment: I think this will not work as you are filling list of integers in the list of integer array(Expected integers).

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but you can have a list of lists like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
lists.add(list);
}
```

Will create Multiple List inside a List.